# Time complexity by solving recurrence relation

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation

I was working on recurrence relation and came across this example

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + log(n)

What will be the time complexity, ie, big O for this relation.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Are you getting stuck on something?

Comment: I worked it out more than a couple of times. I was getting O(nlog(n)). But some of my colleagues answer are conflicting with me as they are getting O(n).

Comment: Hint: they are right ;-) why don't you show your work so that you can be corrected.